# Using Lambda in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

`ThreadWorker` does not execute when I use method reference for creating new object in the constructor of Thread or passing Lambda for creation of new Object.

But it works fine when I create `ThreadWorker` object separately and I pass that to Thread class.

```
public class RunnableImpl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadWorker th= new ThreadWorker();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(th);
        t1.start();
        t1.join();
        System.out.println("Main method terminated");
    }
}

class ThreadWorker implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int[] arr = { 1, 4, 8, 9, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).sum());
    }
}
```

If I use lambda for example:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(ThreadWorker :: new);
```

or

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() ->new ThreadWorker());
```

then there is no output but If I create `ThreadWorker` Object separately then the program is working fine.

Can someone please let me know, how it is possible?

Comment: Thread expects a runnable Object, not a lambda to create a runnable Object. 
Use `new ThreadWorker()` insted of `() ->new ThreadWorker()` or `ThreadWorker :: new`.

Answer (score 6):

Both

```
new Thread(() -> new ThreadWorker());
```

and

```
new Thread(ThreadWorker::new);
```

create a `Thread` whose `Runnable` instance's `run()` method simply creates a `ThreadWorker` instance, and does nothing with it. The `run()` method of `ThreadWorker` is not executed.

They are equivalent to passing the following anonymous class instance:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                         public void run() {
                                             new ThreadWorker ();
                                         }
                                     });
```

If you want to use a lambda expression, you need:

```
new Thread(() -> new ThreadWorker().run());
```

If you want a method reference, you need:

```
new Thread(new ThreadWorker()::run);
```

That said, the following is much simpler:

```
new Thread(new ThreadWorker());
```

Comment: Didnt know about last variant thus +1 (which seams kind of obvious as you can reference instance methods no problem)

Comment: But in this case,ThreadWorker th= new ThreadWorker();Thread t1 = new Thread(th); we are doing the same thing, creating Object and then passing to Thread class.

Comment: @AtishayJain In the case of `Thread t1 = new Thread(th);`, you are passing an instance of `ThreadWorker`, which implements `Runnable`, so the thread will execute its `run()` method when started.

Comment: @AtishayJain No, `() -> new ThreadWorker()` is not the same as `new ThreadWorker()`. One is an instance of  `ThreadWorker`, which implements `Runnable`. The other is a lambda expression implementing a functional interface whose method's body creates a `ThreadWorker` instance. That lambda expression happens to fit the `Runnable` interface, which allows you to pass it to the `Thread` constructor, but it behaves differently.

Comment: @Eran I got it now, So in short Lambda is a method body, like the action which can be performed and it will be performed by a functional interface method which is run() method in this case. Thanks a ton for your quick help.

Comment: @Antoniossss, Oops! Comment withdrawn.